# My tableView Header is not getting stick on top while scrolling, I'm adding a scrollView too at top of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

This is my code

```
private let parentScrollView = UIScrollView()
private let scrollViewContentView = UIView()
private let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)
```

// MARK: Setting Scroll View

```
extension ViewController{
private func setupParentScollView() {
    self.view.addSubview(parentScrollView)
    parentScrollView.delegate = self
    parentScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

private func addParentScollViewConstraints() {
    parentScrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.left.top.right.bottom.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
    }
}
}
```

// MARK: Setting Scroll View's Content View

```
extension ViewController{    
private func setupScollViewContentView() {
    self.parentScrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContentView)
}
private func addScollViewContentViewConstraints() {
    scrollViewContentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalTo(parentScrollView) // Set constraints to cover the entire scrollView.
        make.width.equalTo(parentScrollView)
    }
}
}
```

// MARK: - Setting Up TabelView

```
extension ViewController{     
private func setupTableView() {
    scrollViewContentView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.bounces = false
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
    print("this is from tableView",tableView.style)
    
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
    }
}

func addTableViewConstraints() {
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(searchBottomPaddingView.snp.bottom).offset(100)
        make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(scrollViewContentView)
        make.height.equalTo(parentScrollView.snp.height)
    }
}
}




extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tableView {
        let offsetY = tableView.contentOffset.y
        print("this is from scrollView", offsetY, parentScrollView.contentOffset.x)
        if offsetY > 0 && offsetY <= 120 {
            // Scrolling down, move the parentScrollView up by 120 points
            parentScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: parentScrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 120), animated: true)
        }
        
        if offsetY == 0{
            // Scrolling down, move the parentScrollView up by 120 points
            parentScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: parentScrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
}
```

**here, I don't want to scroll the header of the tableView but since it is inside the contentView of scrollView it is scrolling with it
I generally want to obtain parallax effect while scrolling, please help me.
**

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but would it be a viable solution to simply put a label for your scrollview title set in place on top of the scrollview that isn't contained in the scrollview?